# Play! Framework - Embedded Derby - Permission Denied

Tags: scala, playframework, derby

I try to set up an embedded derby db into a play application - launched by activator.

When I run the application (activator run), the following Exception is thrown:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission("engine","userderbyinternals")
```

Based on what I read from derby document, I am supposed to grant permission using the following command line

```
permission org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission "engine", "usederbyinternals";
```

in "a" security.policy file.

Can someone tell me how to do so at the play application level ? Where is the `security.policy` file located?

Note that I ran from eclipse the exact same `db-access` code in a stand-alone java application without any problem and without having to grant any permission.

Can someone tell me why additional permission configurations are required for running the same code in a scala-play application ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: To learn about how Java security files are used with Derby, start here: https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/security/csecjavasecurity.html

Comment: Got the same issues. Where to place the policy file?